# Black spots on UV mapped objects

Tags: modeling, rendering

First off I am very new to 3D modeling. So please forgive any glaring mistakes.

I am trying to create a scene that simulates satellite imagery using Blender render. When I render any thing but the simplest mesh object like a cube I get black chunks all over the object. However if I move the camera close to the object those spots disappear. The only difference between the cameras is location and focal length. What am I doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my .blend file if it will help. [Example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Qtcx8lSTWwEu6rIbhSiT_BWCNqdHvfQc)

(150km) Camera Render of a UV Sphere
[image: (150km) Camera]

(50m) Camera Render of a UV Sphere
[image]

Comment: One suggestion would be to adjust your camera clipping settings. I'd be happy to take a closer look if you can post your file :)

Comment: I made sure the clipping end was set to 600km. Here is a link to the .blend file [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Qtcx8lSTWwEu6rIbhSiT_BWCNqdHvfQc)

Comment: It's stranger than just black spots: if the world colour is changed to a brighter horizon value, the spherical hull seems to reveal the dashed pattern underneath. It would appear that a camera that distant, with the field of view corresponding to minuscule angles, is causing some errors, but I'm not sure as I'm not too familiar with the inner workings of the original blender internal renderer

Comment: How do I reproduce your error? I don't see the black spots, I tried moving the camera close and far, and it looks fine.

Comment: Perhaps it is my computer, but when ever I place the camera more than 10 or so kilometers above the target the render looks like the first image.

Comment: When I move the camera 10 km above the target, the whole scene is clipped since it's far away. Can you upload a version where the black spots will show as is? This will verify if it's just your computer, or could be the blender version number to.

Comment: The clipping on the camera is set to 600km. On the clipping on the view is set to 1km, but the black spots only show up in the render.

Comment: Do you mean 10m? At 10km, I just see a white dot (the surface the sphere is on), at 10m, I get a view similar to the one you have above, no black spots on either. Hmm, are you getting black spots using cycles render as well?

Comment: When ever I render a scene with the camera named 'Sat' is when I see the problem. The other closer camera is called 'Camera'. I probable should have chosen better names. Also I do not see the same problems using the cycles render only the blender render.

Comment: Ah okay, the Sat camera most likely has some weird setting, it's easier to just delete it and create a new camera. I found your Sat camera. So I just compared it's values with the default camera. The focal length of sat was set at 13 meters vs 3.8mm in the default camera. I think the largest focal length lens in real life is way smaller, so maybe thats why it got all screwy. Anyway, if you change the focal lens size to 3.8mm or some other realistic size, you should be good! You will also need to move the camera closer to the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the answer for completeness!

From the above comments, I compared the "Sat" camera object with a "good camera". The focal length of sat was set at 13 meters vs 3.8mm in the default camera. I think the largest focal length lens in real life is way smaller, so maybe that's why it got all screwy. Anyway, if you change the focal lens size to 3.8mm or some other realistic size, you should be good! You will also need to move the camera closer to the object.

Comment: That is indeed what I ended up doing. I think I was just making everything more complicated than it need to be. Since I am not simulating the curvature of the earth or the atmosphere between camera and target it is a lot simpler to shrink the focal length of the camera and move it closer.